# Common utils library for .net

Tags: .net

Is there any library in .net for common utils like the one from apache in java?

Comment: The FCL not voluminous enough for you?

Comment: What type of utilities are you looking for? Not all of us are familiar with "the one from apache in java."

Comment: Well I was looking for some mapping utils which are included in java's one, I didnt found any classes for mapping a dictionary to an object's properties in the framework's libraries, is there one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A popular mapping library is [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/). I'm not sure whether the *dictionary to object* mapping feature has found its way into the latest version, but you can look at [this AutoMapper work item](http://automapper.codeplex.com/workitem/3266?ProjectName=automapper) for a solution.